# Do consulates verify travel medical insurance?

Tags: schengen, insurance

I will need the insurance only for a week because I'll be spending a week there not 90 days but they want me to get the insurance for 90 days for some reason.

If I buy it for a week and manually modify the expiration date to satisfy them, would they figure it out? Will they call/email the insurance company? Ask them when it starts and ends?

Comment: They probably intend to issue you a visa that allows you to stay for 90 days, since that's easier for them and guards you against delays in your return. I would be extremely surprised if you can buy travel insurance for only a week, and I'd be even more surprised if it was cheaper than 90 day insurance.

Comment: *‘Manually modify’* being a euphemism for deception? Which will almost certainly get you banned if discovered.

Comment: @DJClayworth, where I live you buy travel insurance by the day and each extra day adds to the total cost. I would be very surprised to find 90 day travel insurance cheaper than a short period.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm extremely surprised that you're extremely surprised. Yes, one costs like 12 times more than the other. Wasting money for no reason makes me feel stupid

Comment: @Traveller that's why this question exists

Comment: @user127980 Visa-issuing authorities can typically verify whatever they like. Why take the risk? If you object to paying the price of complying with the terms of the visa, go elsewhere.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to take the risk. I'm just asking a question. Isn't this a Q&A site?

Comment: Immigration officers are very good at spotting deception, and very good at spotting inconsistencies, and they have a lot of resources at their disposal to pursue issues where they feel they need to - up to and including contacting insurance companies to confirm validity.

If you engage in deceptive practices, its not over if you aren't found out the first time - at any point for any further travel to the Schengen zone you risk your prior deception being uncovered and you being banned. 

Buy the insurance, or risk never being able to go back to Schengen and being refused visas elsewhere.

Comment: @user127980 : I have heard of travel insurance that is paid annually, and covers whenever you travel throughout the year. No obligation for a second year. Prices were ~120$/year.

Comment: @Aganju Travel insurance is different than travel medical insurance.

Comment: It would be fraudulent and an offence to modify a document to obtain a benefit otherwise unavailable. It wouldn't necessarily be a problem if you get a 90-day insurance, obtain a visa, refund the original insurance and obtain a new one covering your intended visit.

Comment: Also, if a 90 day insurance has the same or similar daily costs to a 7 day insurance, you may want to change the insurance provider. Most risks come from the fact of taking a trip itself regardless of length and if the pricing doesn't reflect that the price is probably not favourable to you. Schengen only requires 30k EUR coverage so the costs should be fairly low regardless. Many insurances also allow partial refunds if you come back home earlier.

Answer (score 4):

> If I buy it for a week and manually modify the expiration date to satisfy them, would they figure it out?

Possibly yes.

> Will they call/email the insurance company?

Possibly yes.

> Ask them when it starts and ends?

Possibly yes.

Do not commit fraud.