# Fully refundable travel medical insurance

Tags: insurance

I want to be able to cancel the insurance and get a full refund. Preferably until 1 day before it starts. Are there any insurance providers who offer such service? I'm not familiar with how this works

Comment: Adding the country where the insurance will be issued is probably required to give you any meaningful answer. - Here in .NL for example  travel insurance is frequently combined with a cancellation insurance. Then  you  would need that insurance to get your trip fully refunded in case of cancellation, so you wouldn't want to cancel that...

Comment: Do you travel often?  It is worth checking annual policies, they are often not much more than a single trip.  Depending on how often you travel, they might pay off even if one trip is cancelled.  As well as saying where you are, tell us where you want to go.  Here in the UK, I can get worldwide except US and winter sports for a very good price.  Winter sports is an optional extra and so is US cover.

Comment: Is this relayed to https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/173373/6188 ?!?!?

Comment: The country of issue is definitely relevant. In UK there is a mandatory "cooling off period" as described by [Citizens Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/insurance/insurance/cancelling-an-insurance-policy/), but it does say *They may also charge you a small administration fee.* And why wouldn't they? They are in business, not a public service.

Comment: But why should there be such an option? You can't usually ask for a refund of any product purely on the grounds that "you don't need it after all."

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the terms and conditions of the specific policy. Some insurances apparently allow this. See for example:

https://www.insuremytrip.com/travel-insurance-policies-and-claims/canceling-a-policy/

> Single trip medical policies can usually be cancelled any time before departure. While some companies reimburse in full, the majority of them will refund in full less a processing fee.

Comment: But how do I find a policy that fits?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘fits’? An internet search should give you the answer, might take you a bit of research time.

Comment: I mean fully refundable. I researched but couldn't find an option